# Windows workstation is selecting the wrong Windows Firewall Profile

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-11

We are experiencing an unusual problem with some of our workstations. We are seeing some workstations apply the Public Windows Firewall profile despite the fact that the network profile is a domain profile.

I have attached a screen cap of the results of `netsh firewall show state` and the results of `get-netconnectionprofile`. The netsh command shows the firewall profile being "Standard" which is equivalent to Public (I can go into the machine in question and it will tell me, in Windows Firewall, that the Public profile is active in the GUI). The get-netconnectionprofile command is showing that the network is seen as a domain network.

How do we get the machine to understand it's in a domain network and should use the domain profile?

We have tried setting the Network Location Awareness service to Automatic startup so that it is always running. Our understanding is that this service should take care of this type of thing.

Netsh output:

[image]

`get-netconnectionprofile` output:

[image]

Comment: This is usually happening if the computer can connect to wifi and either uses the wrong wifi connection, or something happened with a lan connection where the previous connection failed and it created a new temporary connection, labelling it as public for some unknown reason. A reboot usually fixes this. If you really want to force this, block all traffic on public so that people who get in this state will easily reboot their computer.

Comment: According to your [other question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1409563/intermittent-problem-with-incorrect-windows-firewa) this is a problem with contacting the domain controller.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @bp81: I have a feeling your post is going to be closed soon...